# How to simplify my integrand to make the function Integrate[] work?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, physics

To calculate a physical field, I need to integrate a complicated expression, with Sin and Cos and some 3/2 power. But when I run the Integrate function, it seems running forever. So what could I do to make it possible to get any Integrate result?

My code is simple:

```
magneticField =  Subscript[\[Mu], 0] * mI * r * (Cross[{0, 0, 1}, {x - r*Cos[\[Theta]], y - r*Sin[\[Theta]], 0}])/EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, {r*Cos[\[Theta]], r*Sin[\[Theta]]}]^3 // ComplexExpand // FullSimplify

Integrate[magneticField, {\[Theta], 0, 2*Pi}, GenerateConditions -> False, Assumptions -> (\[Theta] | x | y) \[Element] Reals]
```

Maybe it looks clearer in a picture:
[image]

I have received a pretty neat answer in Wolfram’s Community, here is the link:
https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1601831

Comment: Mathematica cannot decide convergence because of possible singularity ! Perhaps you can find conditions for your parameters `r,x,y`

Comment: Your integration problem probably becomes simpler, if you switch your field evaluation coordinates from `x/y` to polar/cylindrical coordinates, too.

Comment: Please add links to/from the x-post on Wolfram Community.